# Why is return error java.net.UnknownHostException: h-cluster02-n1

Tags: java, ojdbc

I use ojdbc6.jar connect to db with ip scan,
Url connect:
    jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP_SCAN:1521/SERVICE_NAME

but it return error 'java.net.UnknownHostException: h-cluster02-n1'

Why it returned exception,

Please help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

editor your hosts file,
add new line : h-cluster02-n1    ip

Comment: what's problem ?

Comment: I did this, but I don't know what is the problem

Comment: because your machine unknow ip for h-cluster02-n1,you should tell him(example):h-cluster02-n1 192.168.0.1

Comment: Thank GaoKuo, I config connect to IP Scan but it go to host name why?